# Interpolation exercise of coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

The next problem of interpolation I do not know how to approach it. The problem says:

A way to interpolate in two dimensions
the values ​​of $f (x, y)$ in the vertices $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_1, y_2)$, $(x_2, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ of a rectangle, where we seek to approximate $f (x$ *$, y$ * $)$, is:

--Interpolate linearly between $f (x_1, y_1)$ and $f(x_2, y_1)$ giving $f_1$*$(x $ *$, y_1)$

--Interpolate linearly between $f (x_1, y_2)$ and $f(x_2, y_2)$ giving $f_2$*$(x $ *$, y_2)$

--Interpolate linearly between $f (x$* $, y_1)$ and $f(x$* $, y_2)$ giving $f$*$(x $ *$, y$ * $)$

This process can be done in reverse order, interpolating first in $y$ and then in $x$.

the questions are:

$a)$ Does the order in which the variables are considered refer? (If so, the method is at least suspect.)

$b)$ What does it correspond to, in terms of the multivariate polynomial used to interpolate?

Hint: Algebra is heavy, use a symbolic algebra package (like SymPy
for Python).

### -

in what way and with what arguments can I answer the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processes you describe at not neutral with respect to the order in which you do the linear interpolations.

You will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) the description of the "normal" process for bilinear interpolation.

You could easily notice that this is equivalent to a Taylor expansion for a function of two variables for which the derivatives are obtained by differences.

To summarize, what you should use is
$$(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)f(x,y)=$$

$$  f(x_1,y_1)(x_2-x)(y_2-y) + f(x_2,y_1)(x-x_1)(y_2-y)+$$ $$  f(x_1,y_2)(x_2-x)(y-y_1) + f(x_2,y_2)(x-x_1)(y-y_1)$$

**Edit**

Suppose that you have data points $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and what you notice is that for a fixed value of $x$, $z$ is linear with respect to $y$. So, for each given value of $x$ you have
$$z=a+ b y$$ But, now, plotting the values of $a$ and $b$ a functions of $x$, you notice again that $a$ and $b$ are linear with respect to $c$, that is to say
$$a=a_0+a_1 x \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=b_0+b_1x$$ Then
$$z=(a_0+a_1 x)+(b_0+b_1x)y$$ Develop and get
$$z=\alpha+\beta x+\gamma y+\delta x y$$ Same story !

Comment: The formula is correct but I do not think the assessment of the method in the question is correct. If I understood what OP meant, the method in the question is the first method given on the page you linked to, and it is equivalent to your formula.

Answer (score 0):

For single-variable linear interpolation, given a function $g(\theta)$ whose values we know at $\theta = \theta_1$ and $\theta = \theta_2,$ the value interpolated at
$\theta = \theta^*$ is
\begin{align}
g^*(\theta^*)
&= g(\theta_1) + \frac{\theta - \theta_1}
                      {\theta_2 - \theta_1} (g(\theta_2) - g(\theta_1)) \\
&= \frac{\theta_2 - \theta}
        {\theta_2 - \theta_1} g(\theta_1) + \frac{\theta - \theta_1}
                                                 {\theta_2 - \theta_1} g(\theta_2).
\end{align}

So let's try applying this as described in the question. We begin:

> Interpolate linearly between $f(x_1, y_1)$ and $f(x_2, y_1)$ giving $f_1^*(x^*, y_1)$

This implies that
$$
f_1^*(x^*, y_1) =  \frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_1, y_1)
                 + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_2, y_1).
$$

> Interpolate linearly between $f(x_1, y_2)$ and $f(x_2, y_2)$ giving $f_2^*(x^*, y_2)$

This implies that
$$
f_2^*(x^*, y_2) =  \frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_1, y_2)
                 + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_2, y_2).
$$

> Interpolate linearly between $f(x^*, y_1)$ and $f(x^*, y_2)$ giving $f^*(x^*, y^*)$

I assume this actually means we interpolate linearly between
$f_1^*(x^*, y_1)$ and $f_2^*(x^*, y_2).$
This implies that
\begin{align}
f^*(x^*, y^*) &=   \frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} f_1^*(x^*, y_1)
                 + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} f_2^*(x^*, y_2) \\
&= \frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} \left(\frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_1, y_1)
                                   + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_2, y_1)\right)\\
& \qquad
 + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} \left(\frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_1, y_2)
                                   + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} f(x_2, y_2)\right)\\
&=   \frac{(x_2 - x^*)(y_2 - y^*)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_1, y_1)
   + \frac{(x^* - x_1)(y_2 - y^*)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_2, y_1) \\
& \qquad + \frac{(x_2 - x^*)(y^* - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_1, y_2)
         + \frac{(x^* - x_1)(y^* - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_2, y_2).
\end{align}

Now let's try interpolating between $y_1$ and $y_2$ first.
That is, we interpolate
$$
f_1^{**}(x_1, y^*) =  \frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_1, y_1)
                    + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_1, y_2)
$$
and
$$
f_2^{**}(x_2, y^*) =  \frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_2, y_1)
                    + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_2, y_2).
$$
(The double asterisk (**) on each function is meant to denote that these are not the same functions as the single-asterisk functions in the previous interpolation.)

Then the final interpolation (between $x_1$ and $x_2$) is

\begin{align}
f^{**}(x^*, y^*) &=   \frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} f_1^{**}(x_1, y^*)
                    + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} f_2^{**}(x_2, y^*) \\
&= \frac{x_2 - x^*}{x_2 - x_1} \left(\frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_1, y_1)
                                   + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_1, y_2)\right)\\
& \qquad
 + \frac{x^* - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} \left(\frac{y_2 - y^*}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_2, y_1)
                                   + \frac{y^* - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} f(x_2, y_2)\right)\\
&=   \frac{(x_2 - x^*)(y_2 - y^*)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_1, y_1)
   + \frac{(x_2 - x^*)(y^* - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_1, y_2) \\
& \qquad + \frac{(x^* - x_1)(y_2 - y^*)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_2, y_1)
         + \frac{(x^* - x_1)(y^* - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} f(x_2, y_2).
\end{align}

You can confirm that this is equal to the fully developed formula of $f^*(x^*,y^*).$
That is, the result does not depend on which variable you interpolate first.
This result is also equivalent to the formula given in
[this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177695/139123)
and the formula given [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Computation).